# How to enable camera and Mic access in wkwebview

Tags: xcode, macos, whatsapp, wkwebview

I am creating an Mac OSX application to display "Whatsapp web" using WKWebview using Objective C, but the audio recording option and camera access options are not visible.

[Audio Record Option not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCQw3.png)

[Image Capture Option is not Visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xARXz.png)

somebody help me to get both of the options from WKWebview for "Whatsapp Web". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Audio/Video permissions needs to be accepted. Check my follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882825/how-to-implement-notification-requestpermission-method-call-from-html5-in-wk?noredirect=1#comment103331004_40882825

Comment: Found solution??