# How to implement "Notification.requestPermission()" method call from HTML5 in WKWebview for desktop notification

Tags: objective-c, html, macos, notifications, wkwebview

[image: I want to ask permission like this]

I want to ask permission like the above image.

I want to provide permission for desktop notification for the webpage which am loading in WKWebview.

Using HTML5, the webpage is calling the method

> "Notification.requestPermission()"

for getting user permission, if we didnt respond to this method, it defaultly blocking the desktop notification. if anyone knows to implement this method call from HTML5 and give permission for desktop notification. Please let me know. Thank you.
It was nearly 4 months gone, nobody there to solve my problem?

Comment: Your problem is resolved